# Rails: multiple nested models- messaging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm creating a set of nested models for a user-to-user messaging system: `User`, `ConversationUser`, `Conversation`, and `Messages`. `conversation_users` is the complex join table. I believe I've correctly associated the four models, because I can call all of the correct methods on each object, just individually.

Migrations: `messages` have a `:body`, `:user_id` (sender), and a `conversation_id` field. `Conversations` have no fields in them and `conversation_users` have a `user_id` and a `conversation_id` field (being the join table).

My model associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, autosave: true
  has_many :conversation_users, autosave: true
  has_many :conversations, through: :conversation_users
end


class ConversationUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, :conversation_id, presence: true
  before_save :acquire_conversation_id    #tried before_create
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :conversation, autosave: true
  has_many :messages, through: :conversation, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :conversation

  def acquire_conversation_id
    conv = Conversation.create!
    self.conversation_id = conv.id
  end
end


class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, autosave: true
  has_many :conversation_users, autosave: true
  has_many :users, through: :conversation_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages
end


class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :body, :user_id, :conversation_id, presence: true
  belongs_to :user, autosave: true
  belongs_to :conversation, autosave: true
end
```

The way I am trying to create messages from the `user_id` (the sender), but I get a -

```
user = User.find(2)    #or current_user through the controller.
cu = user.conversation_user.build    #tried create also for both
message = cu.messages.create(body: 'Hello World')    #automatically building a conversation
```

Essentially, the way I'm trying to create these messages looks like this in my head:

```
users--->conversation_users
                |
                |
                V
messages<---conversation
```

But I get this error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: You cannot call create unless the parent is saved`

I know where it's getting hung up. A `ConversationUser` can't save without a `conversation_id` that I'm trying to set automatically through these nested builds (where it gets called through `ConversationUser`, the parent model). I can't seem to write a correct method that creates a `Conversation` and sets its id to the `ConversationUser` before it saves. I tried to fix that through the `acquire_conversation_id` method above. I've looked all over for the solution and it seems that some models have `do` blocks that could solve the problem, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

I'm also attempting to automatically set the `message` `user_id` (sender) to the user through this nested build. As you can see, I've already tried the `autosave` feature. Do I need to 'delegate' fields? Is that the problem? I'm honestly stumped. I'd really be appreciative if someone could help out.